# My AspnetCore application does not receive publications from a .net core console application via SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

My AspnetCore application does not receive publications from a .net core console application via SignalR

I have an aspnet core 2.1 web application that contains a SignalR Hub.

I need to make a .net core 2.1 console application that send information to my hub on my web system.

I did a development here, however when I run my console app, no exception appears, but my web application does not receive the information.

See what I've done so far.

Aspnet Core 2.1

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddMvc(
                    config => {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                    options.LoginPath = "/Home/Login";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Usuario/Logout";
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });
            //provedor postgresql
            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
             .AddDbContext<MesContext>(options => 
             options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MesContext")));

            services.AddScoped<SeedingService>();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, SeedingService seedingService)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            seedingService.Seed();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<MesHub>("/MesHub");
            });
        }
    }
```

View Index

```
//teste
    // ATUALIZA LISTAGEM
    connection.on("teste", function (sucesso, msg) {
        if (sucesso) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```

Hub

```
public class MesHub : Hub
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();

        
        public void SendAsync(string message)
        {
            // Call the addMessage method on all clients
             Clients.All.SendAsync("teste", true, message);
        }

        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name);

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
    }
```

Console aplication

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Teste Renan!");

            var url = "https://localhost:44323/meshub";

            var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"{url}")
                .WithAutomaticReconnect() //I don't think this is totally required, but can't hurt either
                .Build();

            var t = connection.StartAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("conected!");
            //Wait for the connection to complete
            t.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine(connection.State);
            

            //connection.SendAsync("SendAsync", "renan");

            connection.InvokeAsync<string>("SendAsync", "HELLO World ").ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an error calling send: {0}",
                                      task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
                }
            });
            Console.WriteLine("enviado!"); 
}
}
```

In the console app I add the Microsoft.aspnetCore.SignalR.Client package

Signalr works very well within the aspnet core web system, as it is not receiving information externally.

I'm forgetting something? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you debug the hub method, does it hit expected method while you invoke it from console client app?

Comment: Is not. So far I have found what is causing the problem, in my Hub I have an OnConnectedAsync method where the name of the group is informed, since no application console I am not setting the group and so it does not connect.

Comment: `in my Hub I have an OnConnectedAsync method where the name of the group is informed` Hi @Renan, please check my new updates.

Answer (score 2):

I define same hub method and do a test to invoke it from the console client, which work as expected.

Besides, I test it with my SignalR console client app, it works well too. If possible, you can test it and check if it works for you.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Client App Starts...");

    Program p = new Program();
    p.Myfunc().Wait();

    Console.ReadLine();

}

public async Task Myfunc()
{
    HubConnection connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("https://localhost:44323/meshub") 
        .Build();

    connection.Closed += async (error) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
        await connection.StartAsync();
    };


    await connection.StartAsync();

    try
    {
        await connection.InvokeAsync("SendAsync", "HELLO World ");
        //await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "console app", "test mes");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
       
}
```

Test Result

[image]

***Updated:***

> in my Hub I have an OnConnectedAsync method where the name of the group is informed

You can try to update the `OnConnectedAsync` method as below, then check if your SignalR console client app can connect to hub and communicate with web client well.

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

    if (name != null)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name);
    }

    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Comment: In your hub class, does the 'OnConnectedAsync' method match my code?

Comment: Does it cause the exception on `OnConnectedAsync` method?

Comment: this if is working. string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

    if (name == null)
    {
        name = "Console";
    }await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name); your if will not working. what do you think about it?

Comment: If name is null, `await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, name);` would throw exception, which seems cause the issue.

Comment: How can I define a name for the console side of the application? today I define within the if I wrote earlier.